# Can't mount network drive - Permission denied

Tags: raspbian, mount

I'm running raspbian on an RPi2B and I'm trying to mount a network drive. I've tried the following:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=admin,password=passwd //192.168.1.1/root /mnt/myshare
```

But I keep getting permission denied error.

I can access this share fine on my macbook pro with the same credentials so I don't understand what's going on.

I have dashes (-) in my password so I tried enclosing it in quotes, escaping the dashes etc. but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Although the commandline environments are similar in overall concept, this goal is at a level where should probably not expect the method of doing this on a Linux system to be exactly the same as on OSX.  Have you tried reading up on recommended procedures for doing this on Linux in general?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually I mounted the share in finder not in terminal. I'm a linux newbie so I got the command from a google search. I've tried many variations on it but all have yielded the same result. I came across one post which led me to believe that it could be to do with the encryption type used but I don't know how to check the encryption type or how to change it...

Comment: You might do better on unix.stackexchange.com - this would only be a pi issue to the extent that there would need to be pi version of whatever cifs packages are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding sec=ntlm to the options so that in your example the command would read

sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlm,username=admin,password=passwd //192.168.1.1/root /mnt/myshare

KenR

Comment: That gives me: mount error(11): Resource temporarily unavailable